# Distinct column values concatenation (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have the table like this:

[image]

I need to get distinct column values concatenation:

[image]

I'm trying to use `Select CONCAT_WS(', ', column1, column2, column3, column4)`, but I'm not getting the desired result with 'distinct'

Comment: Unpivot (using UNION) then use CONCAT(DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0):

First get all the pairs of (row ID, column VALUE) - then group by row ID and concatenate only the distinct values in that group:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT VALUE) FROM
(SELECT ID, COL_1 AS VALUE FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, COL_2 FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, COL_3 FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, COL_4 FROM TABLE
UNION ALL) AS TEMP_1
GROUP BY ID
```